# Office 365 REST API calls from a .net console application

Tags: c#, active-directory, office365, outlook-restapi, office365-restapi

Please note that this question is not regarding generic REST service calling. Its about specific Office 365 REST service API.

To be specific I need to utilize the 'Contact' API here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/contacts-rest-operations#UsingtheContactsRESTAPI

I was wondering how the Office 365 REST services can be utilized in a **Console** application. There are tools to deal with the APIs from Web, mobile and windows store apps. But I found no resource for console application.

I have the application created on the application registration portal here: https://apps.dev.microsoft.com

So I already have the Application Id, Application Secrets, Platforms Mobile application (Client Id, Redirect URI)

I think I will need the authentication token (I have the Username, password).
And use that to call the REST services.

Comment: Can you share what you have done so far, what specific API(s) you need to call, and what you are doing currently that is not working?  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for suggestions on how to ask.  If you just want to know how to call a REST API from a console app, see e.g. [How to call REST API from a console application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22627296) or [Best way to call a JSON WebService from a .NET Console](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270464).

Comment: @dbc, I have updated the question.

Answer (score 5):

Currently for Office 365 Mail, Calendar, and Contacts APIs two versions are supported: `v1` and `v2`

**About REST API v2**

The Office 365 API services use Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) to provide secure authentication and authorization to users' Office 365 data. Azure AD implements authorization flows according to the [OAuth 2.0 protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749).

To allow your application access to the Office 365 APIs, you need to [register your application with Azure AD](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/add-common-consent-manually).

---

In case of API `v1` version, since it supports `Basic` authentication, the following example demonstrates how to read contacts in console app using user credentials:

**Example**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
  
        ReadContacts().Wait();
    }

    private static async Task ReadContacts()
    {
        var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
        handler.Credentials = new NetworkCredential()
        {
            UserName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserName"],
            Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"]
        };

        using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
        {
            var url = "https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/contacts";
            var result = await client.GetStringAsync(url);

            var data = JObject.Parse(result);

            foreach (var item in data["value"])
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item["DisplayName"]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```